# Does the verb "continue" always require an action-describing word right after it?

Tags: verbs

Does the verb "continue" always require an action-describing word right after it? Can I drop it if the action is clear from the context?

For example, can I say:

> Throughout the whole first semester Linda remained passive and didn’t
>   participate much. She was never naughty, but didn’t show any
>   enthusiasm either. In the first half of the second semester **she
>   continued in the same way**.

or should I say

> ...she continued **to behave** in the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what an "action-describing word" is, but there are several ways you can finish a sentence after "continue" other than "to [verb]":

- she continued on
- she continued in this fashion
- she continued as if nothing had changed

I think in your particular example, your second choice "to behave" is much clearer. The first one isn't ungrammatical, but it's just hard to read - she continued *what* exactly? She continued attending school? She continued not showing enthusiasm? etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you!